# How can i demonstrate that rank(AB-BA)=rank(AB+BA)?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

There is a natural $n,$ such that $n≥2$ where $A, B$ are square matrices of order n, idempotents, and that det($A$$-$$B$)$≠$$0$

I tried to use the idempotence propriety, so I thought about starting from [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QxYif.png),continuing with [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4OZty.png) and proving that it's not equal to zero.

I know that **(A+B)(A+B-I)=AB+BA** and **(A-B)(A+B-I)=AB-BA** but I don't know how to actually proof that their ranks are equal.

I would be more than happy to receive some ideas.

Comment: Please share also your thoughts about the problem.

Comment: @Lauraa Note that askers are expected to provide context for their questions, as [is explained here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). Please [edit] your question to tell us where you encountered this question, what you have tried so far, and any other relevant thoughts you might have about the question.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
$$
(2I-A-B)(AB-BA) = AB-BA+ABA-BAB = (A-B)(AB+BA) \\
(2I-A-B)(AB+BA) = AB+BA-ABA-BAB = (A-B)(AB-BA)
$$
Now you can show that each element of the kernel of (the linear map represented by) $AB+BA$ is also an element of the kernel of (the linear map represented by) $AB-BA$ and vice versa, which in turn shows the equality of the ranks.

Note that you can use $(A-B)^{-1}$ but not $(2I-A-B)^{-1}.$